# How do I check if a particular RAM is compatible with a motherboard in a laptop (before buying)?

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, motherboard, upgrade

I want to upgrade my laptop Ram , actually i have `8 GO` and i want to pass to `12 GO` or `16 GO`.

I have professional Laptop `DELL LATITUDE E6530 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz`

I used a software `CPU-z` to know my actual ram and buying something is similar that i have.

[image]

I have been searched on the net some similar ram with the `Max Bandwith PC3-12800 (800 MHZ) (see the red box on the picture)` but i didn't found it , i found something with `1600 MHZ` but i don't know if this frequency `1600 MHZ` will be work fine with my actual ram.

Please i want to know what's the right thing to see if i want to buy a ram to do an upgrade ? and if i buy a `ram with 1600 MHZ` i doesn't do a `hardware` or `software` problem  ?

Comment: Use the [crucial advisory tool](http://uk.crucial.com/)

Comment: DDR3 laptop memory is what you want but verify your device even supports 16GB

Comment: If I understand correctly, 800 Mhz is the absolute frequency of the RAM chip for PC3-12800. When it's DDR (Data Double Rate) it becomes x2 i.e. 1600 Mhz. So what you have is in fact 1600MHz DDR3.   It's a different story if your laptop would support 16 GB or not.

Comment: @pat2015 my laptop support 16 GB because i called the support of DELL and the men told i can do 16 GB

Comment: @Ramhound my laptop support 16 GB

Comment: You have verified that information by reading the service manual for your device.  Dell support is notoriously carelessly with confirmation of things like this

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to jump onto the [Kingston Memory Search](https://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/Options) page and/or [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/) websites (which lets you select by entering the system or downloading a program to scan your system) to find appropriate memory for your computer.    I'd typically buy the recommended memory because of guarantees, but you could always use the results to find the characteristics of the memory and buy something else.